# How to persist PRICE information using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In SQL it is a usual practice to store money amounts in columns of type `DECIMAL(10,2)`. However when it comes to Hibernate mapping, I'd wish to avoid mapping values to floating point numbers. Is there a way to map column to an integer containing number of cents?

Comment: Not sure why you want to use an integer to store a floating point value, instead of using a float or a double. By the way if you want to use a long in Java, you could do the same in your SQL db schema.

Comment: Its not possible, please check the answer below.

Comment: Simply use BigDecimal in your entities rather than Float or Double, and map to either DECIMAL or NUMERIC fields in your DB. This will give you exactly the precision you want as well as well-defined rounding modes.

Answer (score 3):

The practice of using a decimal(10,2) for money is terrible.
Also, the practice of using a floating point value for money is a monkey technique (as in, only a monkey would think it makes sense to store a fixed point value with a non-exact, floating point number).

Instead, determine the smallest monetary value that you need to store, for example 1/1000 of a euro, and store money as an integral multiple of that value.
Continuing this example, the value 2.57 euros would be represented by 2570 in the money column.

Money math should always be performed with integral values.

Side note:

Proof of monkey:

```
float value1 = .1;
float value2 = .2;
float value3 = value1 + value2;

if (value3 == .3)
    printf ("m1. you are not a monkey");
else
    printf ("m2. you are a monkey.  learn something about floating point representation");
```

message m1 will never display

Comment: @DwB, could you please explain what's wrong about `DECIMAL(10,2)` in practice?

Comment: Decimal columns in a database translate to a floating point number in most programming languages.  Integer is significantly better.  Also, why do you care about the presentation of the number in the database.  Represent the data correctly then display it correctly.  The representation and display can (and with money, should) be different.